# How to call multiple webservices in loop in php without affecting GUI

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl

I have a server client application. In this my server is php based application on a central location and clients are local servers developed in php and located at individual machine.
I have aGUI on my central server where i selects the local clients and sends the string message to them using webservice which is their on each local machine. Currently it is like when i clicks on send button it takes ip of each local machine from database and calls the webservice in for loop but it takes lots of time for looping if i selects more local clients. So how can i tell my central server to do this work in background

Comment: run the job in the background call the script via the cli using exec()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a job queue like [BeanStalk](http://kr.github.com/beanstalkd/)